# Не работает сравнение времени Delphi

Tags: delphi

При сравнении времени всегда получается -1. Еще если задебажить, то можно заметить, что по какой-то причине в куске кода на фото не переводится дата из формата xx.xx.xxxx в xx/xx/xxxx, который пригодный для сравнения дат. Задача: сравнить дату из TListView с текущей датой +1 месяц и обновить потом TListView. Помогите разобраться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
procedure TFMain.BTimeSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  TempStr1, TempStr2: TDateTime;
  TempStrPoint: string;
  i, j, k: integer;
  X: integer;
  pCurr: PNode;
  ListSize: integer;
begin
  TempStr1 := Date;
  TempStr1 := IncMonth(TempStr1);

  pCurr := pHead;
  ListSize := GetListSize(pCurr);
  FMain.ListViewMain.Clear;
  pCurr := pCurr.Next;
  j := 0;

  for i := 1 to ListSize do
  begin
    TempStrPoint := pCurr^.Value.PrEnds;
    for k := 1 to length(TempStrPoint) do
    begin
      if TempStrPoint[i] = '.' then
      begin
        TempStrPoint[i] := '/';
      end;
    end;
    TempStr2 := StrToDate(TempStrPoint);

    if (CompareTime(TempStr2,TempStr1)=LessThanValue)  then
    begin
      FMain.ListViewMain.Items.Add.Caption := pCurr.Value.PrName;
      with FMain.ListViewMain.Items[j].SubItems do
      begin
        Add(pCurr.Value.PrTask);
        Add(pCurr.Value.PrExecutor);
        Add(pCurr.Value.PrDirector);
        Add(pCurr.Value.PrStarts);
        Add(pCurr.Value.PrLasts);
        Add(pCurr.Value.PrEnds);
      end;
      inc(j);

    end;
    pCurr := pCurr.Next;

  end;

end;
```

Для проверки работоспособности, можете подать вместо даты из TListView любую другую дату, которая изначально в формате xx.xx.xxxx

Comment: Не видя что у вас там в датах действительно лежит - помочь вам затруднительно.

Comment: Простите а зачем изобретать велосипеды? [StringReplace()](https://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/StringReplace.php.html)
и что за мания наставить миллиард бегин\энд? это же не си где они короткие... `for k := 1 to length(TempStrPoint) do if TempStrPoint[i] = '.' then TempStrPoint[i] := '/';` всё, ни единого блока бегин\энд тут не нужно :)

Comment: В цикле `for k ...` для доступа по индексу ошибочно используете `i` вместо `k`. И цикл `for i` вообще надо заменить на `while pCurr <> nil`.